# How to query multiple documents in mongodb with conditional params

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have message document with `groupId` and `createdTS` fields.
and for query i have array of objects with `groupId` and `lastVisit`.
I want to query all messages per `groupId` after `lastVisit`

I tried with `$in` with groupIds but it is not filtering `createdTS` with `lastVisit`

member schema

```
const GroupMemberSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: { type: String, required: true },
  groupId: { type: String, required: true },
  addTS: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  lastVisit: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

Message Schema

```
const GroupMessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: { type: String, required: true },
  groupId: { type: String, required: true },
  content: { type: String, required: true },
  createdTS: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

for query

```
GroupMessage.find({groupId: {$in: groupIds}})
```

Comment: Can you try to go on with a suitable sample data and some codes of what you have tried so far.

Comment: This sound like you might be looking for `$setIntersection`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correct then you need to fetch records that match each `groupId` and at the same time are greater than appropriate `lastVisit`. If to translate it to MongoDB query it would be something like this:

```
{
  "$or": [
    {
      "$and": [
        { "groupId": _groupId[i] }, 
        { "createdTS": { "$gt": _lastVisit[i] } } 
      ]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Where `_groupId[i]` and `_lastVisit[i]` are array elements for list of groups and lastVisit timestamps.

Comment: so i have to `.map` on array of objects and generate this query

Comment: As an option you can do it. Or you can use `forEach` or simple `for` loop to build the query

Comment: I made the match with map and used it with aggregate to get result.
Thanks it is working now